# Add CSS-Class after a Typescript function returns true

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add a certain css class to my Div after a function returns a true value:

`<div class="{{doubleClick === true ? 'cell-select' : 'cell-deselect'}}"></div>`

The function doubleClick returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the same result by others ways and avoid these cases  `{{func()}}` or `[prop]="func()"` angular evaluate this function when any ui change is happend like click another button or write something in textbox and that is not related to the method it self

we can call the function to update a property and bind this property to the ngClass directive

*template*

```
<div [ngClass]="{'cell-select':clicked ,'cell-deselect': !clicked }" 
     (dblclick)="doubleClick()">
  Content
 </div>
```

*component*

```
  clicked = false;
  doubleClick() {
    this.clicked = true;
  }
```

you can toggle a value

*template*

```
<div [ngClass]="{'cell-select':toggled ,'cell-deselect': !toggled }" 
     (dblclick)="toggleDoubleClick()">
  toggle
 </div>
```

*component*

```
toggled= false;
  toggleDoubleClick(){
    this.toggled = !this.toggled;
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53707752-1)

and if you don't want to create a property you can put all the logic in the template

```
<div [ngClass]="{'db-clicked':elm.clicked}" #elm (dblclick)="elm.clicked = true">
    db click {{elm.clicked ?':)':':('}}</div> 
 <button (click)="elm.clicked = false">Reset</button>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53707752-2)

Answer (score 2):

use the `ngClass`. Also, use the parenthesis since `doubleClick` is a function

```
<div [ngClass]="{'cell-select': doubleClick(),'cell-deselect': !doubleClick() }">Content</div>
```

Or simply you can do this without ngClass.

```
<div class="{{doubleClick() ? 'cell-select' : 'cell-deselect'}}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It does not seem to work, i get : `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 17`

Comment: Every time angular digest cycle run, this will run. Simply quite a lot